# Can we serve static files in a node module for a server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

I'm a begginer so sorry if the question seems stupid but I'm developping a NodeJs server and I'm currently using this (in backend/server.js) to have my public files :

```
app.use(express.static(Path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public')));
```

But I would like to know if I can add a package of a node module in my paths like :

```
app.use(express.static(Path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules/fuelsdk-node')));
```

My directory is set like this :[image]

How should I import my node module ?
Can I use both at the same time ? Or do I have to do it an other way? Thanks !

Comment: If you want to serve the files inside `node_modules/fuelsdk-node` this is perfectly fine basically. I just wonder what the purpose of that would be. And yes you can use both together.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, questions along the lines of "Will this code work" are terrible. Instead **try it**, then do some debugging, and then ask a question along the lines of "I wrote this code, I want X to happen, but Y happened instead.  I did A to debug this and I found B. I don't understand C.".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is NOT recommended to call static files from the node_modules folder directly. Instead, a good practice is to use redirections. Idea is to have a link that will call a static resource from the node_modules folder.

```
app.use("link", "physical address");
```

in your case, it will be something like:

```
app.use("/", express.static(Path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public')));
app.use("/fuelsdk-node", express.static(Path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules/fuelsdk-node')));
```

Now you can call your static files by relevant to the link.

---

For better understanding please see an example of usage bootstrap from node_modules

```
npm install jquery
npm install bootstrap
```

server.js file

```
// grab express
var express = require("express");

// create an express app
var app = express();

// CONFIGURE THE APP
// ==================================================
// tell node where to look for site resources
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')); // redirect CSS bootstrap
app.use('/js',  express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js')); // redirect JS bootstrap
app.use('/jquery',  express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist')); // redirect JS jquery
// create an express route for a homepage
// http://localhost:8080/
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('/index.html');
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Server has started');
```

public/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Static Files</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/bootstrap.min.css' />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <strong>It works</strong> Static files from node_modules. css & javascript are connected by redirected link
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.alert').alert();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! :)

Comment: I know this is quite an old answer, but I'm wondering what is the rationale behind linking it indirectly instead of directly? I understand we are trying to put everything in the public folder, but is it not the same than if we simply grab it from the node_modules folder? Also, how can this be extended into multiple CSS files from different folders?