# How to get bootstrap.js,jquery and popper.js to work when using NPM to add Bootstrap to a project?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have set up a basic project and added Bootstrap through npm. Despite sass successfully working, I am having some trouble to load the javascript files Bootstrap components depend on. It's worth mentioning that I am using a Vagrant Box (virtual machine) which serves up the project. Plus, I am using the browser-sync plugin which starts up a mini-server and references the one from the VM. I hope I am explaining myself well!

**Index file** (in public folder)

```
<div class="carousel-inner" data-slide-to="2">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100 " src="images/logo.jpeg" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/01.jpeg" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/02.jpeg" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
  <script src="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "bstrap",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build-task:scss-compile": "node-sass-chokidar --source-map true scss -o public/css",
    "build-task:autoprefixer": "postcss public/css/*.css --use autoprefixer postcss-nested -d public/css",
    "sass:build": "npm-run-all -p build-task:*",
    "sass:watch": "chokidar \"scss/**/*.scss\" -c \"npm run sass:build\"",
    "sass:browsersync": "browser-sync start --proxy \"strap.test\" --files \"public\"",
    "dev": "npm-run-all -p sass:*"
  }
```

**Console errors**

[image: Errors when resquesting the js files]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we serve static files in a node module for a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50913259/can-we-serve-static-files-in-a-node-module-for-a-server)

Comment: @Dshiz Humm... I am using a mini-server provided by browser-sync which is referencing the vagrant server (since I am using a VM homestead box) so I can't see how this could be relevant to my question. Your question though made me realized that the node_modules folder is sitting in the project root meaning is not being served up. True. But then, I confess, I am still struggling here. Really sorry if I am being annoying now...

Comment: You may need to clarify your question and be more specific with your description and code for what you are trying to solve.

Comment: I hope the question and description make sense now.

Answer (score 1):

When I use NPM with Bootstrap I don't actually deploy the `node_modules` folder to the server (production/staging), so when I'm building local projects, I tend to import these node modules into my main js src file and compile them to distribution folder.

If you are directly calling `node_modules` like you are, you will have upload the `node_modules` to your production/staging environments too, which I don't think is ideal.

How I import jQuery, Bootstrap and Popper into my `src/js/theme.js`, which then compiles to `dist/js/theme.js`, is like this...

```
// load jquery
import jQuery from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;

// pull in our vendors
require('bootstrap');
require('popper.js');

// all your custom js here...
```

And then simply get the distribution `theme.js` file like this...

```
<script src="/dist/js/theme.js"></script>
```